# Visual Studio 2015 slow while editing and debugging

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm having trouble with Visual Studio 2015 Pro for one specific solution. The solution is a ASP.Net Web Forms application with 10 projects. The following problems only appear in this solution:

- Closing the solution takes 20-30s
- Opening the solution takes 1min
- VS becomes completely unresponsive while opening/closing the solution
- Typing has a small lag (~200ms)
- IntelliSense for c#-Code also lags
- IntelliSense for JavaScript does not work at all (might be an unrelated issue though)
- Opening an .aspx file in designer takes 5-10s
- Stopping a debugging session takes 15-30s and VS becomes completely unresponsive during that. Staring the debugging session is actually faster than stopping it.

When I was using VS 2012, these problems did not appear. I got the described problems under Windows 7 Pro and Windows 10 Pro. Reinstalling Windows and Visual Studio did not help either.
For other solutions (Windows Forms, WPF), these problems do not appear. I have also tried to delete the project's *suo file, which is known to cause perfomance issues when it gets too big. Strange thing now is that VS does not create a new *suo file in the project directory. My development machine is surely fast enough to handle the project (a few 100k LOC). I'm not using any 3rd-party plugings like ReSharper. Other things I did while troubleshooting:

- Disable code lens
- Install all available updates
- Cache debugging symbols

I have tried several possible fixes found via Googling, but nothing helped so far. Does anybody have another suggestion what the cause of the problems might be?

**Update**:
Deleting all breakpoints using the function provided for that fixed some of ther problems. I can now open/close the solution within <5s and starting/stopping debugging now goes smoothly. However, input lag, designer lag and problematic IntelliSense still persist. Deleting contents in "AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" did not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate [**Why Visual Studio 2015 freezes crashes hangs on Designer view?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37681942/why-visual-studio-2015-freezes-crashes-hangs-on-designer-view)

Comment: 10 projects does not tell much about the size of a project. You might have 5 or 500 files in each project... and each project might have many references.

If you have large projects, you want desktop i7 CPU with a lot of memory and SSD drive.

Comment: If you have 10 projects, you might try to create solutions with only some of the project to see if the problem is specific to a project. And also ensure that you have minimal reference in yours projects.

Comment: Its not a duplicate; the problem described there only makes up a small portion of my issues and the solution suggested does not work for me either.
As mentioned, my solution contains a few 100k LOC, maybe 300k. 
My dev machine uses a Core i7-4790K, Samsung 850 Pro SSD, 32Gb RAM...

Comment: install the VS2015 update 3 + latest update http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2016/08/VS14-KB3165756-25425.html and look if it faster now

Comment: Already done, did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think that many issues can cause this type of problem & you can never give up enough details to help identify these types of issues ...

it could be because of a million difrent things ....

I googled it and found some interesting solutions ....

have a look [Here](http://blog.geocortex.com/2007/12/07/slow-visual-studio-performance-solved/)

be sure to check out the comments !

Comment: I am hoping that someone that has had the same problem might see this and point me to a solution. I had already found the link you provided and tried the suggested fix, but no luck here.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following to resolve issues in java-script and .aspx files a bit:

- Remove unnecessary contents from **_references.js** file. it should be present in **Scripts** folder.
- Right click on the file and **uncheck "Auto Sync Java-script References"**

Hope it helps

Comment: "Update JavaScript references" added a lot of new references to _references.js, but I still got no AutoComplete or IntelliSense. What strikes me as strange is that it works in another ASP.Net project of mine, so the problem has to be related to the solution...