# Visual Studio XAML designer System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException Timespan error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015, designer

I am getting an unhandled exception in the XAML Designer seemingly randomly, it occurs more often when I am looking through the properties window for an object but I can't see a rhyme or reason as to why it occurs, I have been googling through this error for the past week and haven't found anything that fixes the issue, a couple of different unhandled exceptions but not one like mine, here is the error I am getting:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

TimeSpan period must be less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue.
Parameter name: value
```

I can reload the designer and work for a few minutes again before the unhandled exception occurs again, anyone have any ideas?
I have also tried repairing visual studio to no avail.

Comment: You are saying that this is an error from the Visual Studio itself while viewing the designer?

Comment: @FirstStep Correct, this error occurs while using the XAML Designer within Visual Studio 2015 itself

Comment: Check this solution of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37681942/why-visual-studio-2015-freezes-crashes-hangs-on-designer-view

Comment: Closed VS, cleared all content from that folder, restarted, and after a few minutes got the same unhandled exception :(
Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Did you mess with its configuration anyway? Did you try update? Did you try repair? Did you try un-install re-install? Does it happen on any project?

Comment: Didn't mess with config at all, repaired, removed all temp files on Appdata and windows temp, this occurs on any WPF project, I don't have any problems working in Winforms. Just noticed that update 3 is available for VS2015, I'll get that installed and see if that fixes it

Comment: Download Update-3 and update. If it did not work, remove the whole thing and install all over again. It is frustrating but you have to do it.

Comment: Looks like Update 3 fixed it, I should have checked for updates, thank you for your help @FirstStep!

Comment: Good :) Glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating VS2015 to update 3 fixed the issue.